# Theoretical basis for wormholes

Tags: general-relativity, wormholes, exotic-matter

From what little I know about general relativity, energy (and equivalently mass) distorts and curves spacetime due to the Einstien Field Equations. I also know "wormholes" are theoretically solutions to the field equations, that connect two points in spacetime.

However, how do these two definitions work with eachother? Energy distorts space into a fourth dimension, I understand that, but using that description, how could a wormhole "connect" those two points? The way I've seen it describes it folding over a piece of paper and poking a pencil through it - but that seems like a cop out. What's the equivalent of "folding" in physics, and does a theoretical wormhole *actually* fold the space?

How can two distortions in a uniform 3D space possibly connect to eachother?

Comment: **Any** physical description is a cop out, if you want to put it that way. You are reading too much into attempts to describe physically, what even math fails at, ultimately.

Comment: Can you explain what it would mean to "actually" fold space?

Comment: @probably_someone To literally fold into halves our 3 dimensional universe within four dimensions and poke a hole through it.

Comment: What does "literally" mean in that context? How would the meaning of your statement differ if it wasn't there?

Comment: @probably_someone I'm not sure if you're making a semantic or a physics point - I don't think my statement would differ. To fold  our third dimensional universe over on iteself in four dimensions.

Comment: The point of my question is simple. Your original question was, "Does a wormhole _really_ fold space?" Your answer says that there's no difference between folding space and "really folding space." So what is the meaning of your question now?

Comment: @probably_someone The meaning of my question now is "Does a wormhole fold space?"

Comment: Then the answer is yes, as that's what a wormhole is defined as.

Comment: Assuming a suitable definition of "fold," that is.

Comment: @probably_someone Man, you should teach physics. That was the most natural a-ha moment I've had in a long time. You're completely right. It seems obvious now. Thank you!

Comment: There is no folding. You are thinking of a extrinsic space or dimension where the spacetime folds over. The math for the wormhole is not that way, it is purely intrinsic 4D spacetime being multiply connected, it is not extra dimensions, it is pure topology and 4D spacetime. All that intuitive thinking is just not real - think topology